# Does improving weapons make them heavier or lighter?

Tags: mass-effect-3

In the shuttle bay, Shepard has the option to pay credits to upgrade his aresnal from, for instance, Avenger I to Avenger II, etc.

The improvement is listed as "improves damage, ammo capacity, and weight". Does that mean it's making my weapons heavier or lighter? Is it better to keep weapons un-upgraded so that I can keep a greater cooldown reduction, or is it the opposite?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The upgrades reduce the weight. See below the comparison between the base level Raider I shotgun versus the upgraded Raider V.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Upgrades that "improve" weight *reduce* weight, such as the [SMG Ultralight Materials](http://masseffect.wikia.com/wiki/Weapon_Upgrades_%28Mass_Effect_3%29#SMG_Ultralight_Materials). Since it's an upgrade it reduces the weight. To my knowledge all upgrades are purely positive.

Comment: Those aren't the upgrades he is talking about. Though I believe your answer is still correct.

Comment: Incorrect - some modifications are a trade off; 60% less damage for 25% of damage bypassing armor.

Comment: @AdamMusch isn't it 40% **additional** damage to health underneath armor?

Comment: @kotekzot Health doesn't exist "under armor" in ME3, and NO modifications are trade offs, Adam Musch is completely incorrect. See [this question](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/54156/how-does-the-assault-rifle-piercing-mod-work)

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by health not existing under armor, but there are certainly some foes around the have an armor bar that must be depleted before damage to health can be dealt.

Comment: @kotekzot I've definitely never seen one. PS3 version, which are you playing? Beaten the game 3 times and numerous online matches.

Comment: Yes, I stand corrected; the 25% less damage is if the shot penetrates.

Comment: @BenBrocka I played it on PC. Can't recall which it was offhand, but it was probably brutes, since non-fleshy foes don't have health bars. I remember reading that the upgrade was pointless against most armored enemies as they didn't have an underlying health bar, though that may have been wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Lighter. NEVER heavier. Upgrades will always decrease weight as well as increasing damage, accuracy, capacity, and firing rate(for most weapons.)