# What are the armor thickness of ME3 enemies?

Tags: mass-effect-3

Plenty of ME3 questions address how piercing mods work: "[How does the Assault Rifle Piercing Mod work?,](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/54156/1770)" "[Does the piercing mod allow me to shoot through cover/objects?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/55908/1770)."

However how thick are enemies? For example, how thick is the guardian's shield? What is the thickness of some cover?

Comment: I guarantee there is no enemy out there that has half a meter thick armor. That is probably the thickness of the armor on the Normandy.

Comment: @Resorath 0.5 meter isn't that thick. I am willingly to bet there are cover in ME3 that is that thick.

Comment: Are you really just asking whether armor piercing works on all armored enemies?  Because it seems like the other questions make that a pretty clear "Yes".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The thickness shouldn't be an issue, the armor peircing will work fine on all armored targets.